# Align center messing up definition list

Tags: css, html, xhtml, xhtml-transitional

I want to create a contact me section on a website i'm making but the problem is my whole website has `text-align:center` and i am using a definition list for the contact information. is there a way i can still use the wrapper for my page but align the text to the left without it going out of the white border?

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";

html {
    text-align: center
}

#container {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:50 auto;
    margin-bottom:50 auto;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#666666;
}

#body1 {
    background-color:#666666;
    width:1000px;
    height:405px;;
    border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

#body2 {
    background-color:#666666;
    width:1000px;
    height:800px;;
    border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

#body3{
    background-color:#666666;
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;;
    border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

#body4{
    background-color:#666666;
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;;
    border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

#body5{
    background-color:#666666;
    width:1000px;
    height:500px;;
    border:3px solid #FFFFFF;
    margin-top:50px auto;
}

.navbar {
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#999;
    text-align:center;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:none;
    padding-left:0px;    
}


ul.navbar li {
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
}

ul.navbar a {
    color:white;
    font-size:20px;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul.navbar a:hover {
    color:#000000;
    background-color:#CCC;
}

body {
    background-color:#333333;
}

#portrait {
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    right:420px;


}

#headerhome {
    position:relative;
    bottom:130px;
    left:50px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#CCCCCC
}

#goal {
    margin-left:40px;
    text-align:left;
    text-indent:40px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:110px
}

.tab {
    margin-left:40px;
}

#contact {
    position:relative;
    right:390px;
    text-align:left
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Joe Scotto | Contact</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="body3">
<img src="banner.png" width="1000" height="100" />
<!--Navbar Start-->
<center>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li><li><a href="about.html">About</a></li><li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li><li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li><li><a href="biography.html">Biography</a></li>
    </ul>
</center>
<!--Navbar End-->
<div id="contact">
<dl>
    <dt><h3>Phone Number</h3></dt>
        <dd>XXX-XXX-XXXX</dd>
    <dt><h3>Email Address</h3></dt>
        <dd>XXXXXX@gmail.com</dd>
</dl>
</div>
</div>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can yo supply a fiddle

Comment: `#contact {
    position:relative;
    right:390px;
    text-align:left
}` You have written perfect.. Because CSS goes from top to bottom and over-writes the properties with new values..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
dl {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Edit: I added the above to your css and the list was aligned to the left.

Comment: Lars, Is this a comment or an answer? If an answer please explain why that should work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly then your problem can be fixed using two things:

- in #contact css add "!important" after the "text-align:left;" on the same line
- add margin if it overlaps.

If this doesnt answer your question please send me a link so i can see what is happening.

hope i helped.

Answer (score 0):

`#contact {
    text-align:left;
}` Might work. `position:relative;` Try removing. Because CSS goes from top to bottom and over-writes the properties with new values.. [Check this](http://jsfiddle.net/vqpwe/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the "contact block" in the body3 (which is centered), why you added the code - "right: 390px;" to the #contact, I do not see the reason. So if you delete it everything will be okay.

Answer (score 0):

remove the text-align:center from css in html tag and add text-align attribute in every div tag so you will get align as you want